# do you have to pass SSO profile credentials in order to assume the IAM role using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, assume-role

I have my config file set up with multiple profiles and I am trying to assume an IAM role, but all the articles I see about assuming roles are starting with making an sts client using

```
import boto3 client = boto3.client('sts')
```

which makes sense but the only problem is, It gives me an error when I try to do it like this. but when I do it like this, while passing a **profile** that exists in my config file, it works. here is the code below:

```
import boto3 session = boto3.Session(profile_name="test_profile")
sts = session.client("sts")
response = sts.assume_role(
RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/role-name",
RoleSessionName="test-session"
)
new_session = Session(aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'], aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
```

when other people are assuming roles in their codes without passing a profile in, how does that even work? does boto3 automatically grabs the default profile from the config file or something like that in their case?

Comment: Read here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#guide-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This line:

```py
sts = session.client("sts")
```

tells boto3 to create a session using the `default` credentials.

The credentials can be provided in the `~/.aws/credentials` file. If the code is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, boto3 will automatically use credentials associated with the **IAM Role associated with the instance**.

Credentials can also be passed via Environment Variables.

See: [Credentials — Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html)